# Projeto MVC em C# lançando Exception System.InvalidCastExecption

Tags: c#, winforms, mvc

Caros colegas, estou tentando aprender desenvolver um projeto em MVC. Porém estou tendo algumas dificuldades. Ao executar o programa, ele executa normalmente, porém quando quero gravar uma nota de entrada de produtos lança essa exceção de acordo com a imagem abaixo:

[image: Imagem do Erro]

Segue abaixo o código fonte da Classe Fornecedor:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ModelProject
 {
    public class Fornecedor
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string CNPJ { get; set; }

        protected bool Equals(Fornecedor other)
        {
            return Id.Equals(other.Id);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
                return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
                return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Fornecedor))
                return false;
            return Equals((Fornecedor)obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();            
        }
     }
 }
```

Código do Fornecedor Controller

```
using ModelProject;
using PersistenceProject;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ControllerProject
{
    public class FornecedorController
    {
        private Repository repository = new Repository();

        public Fornecedor Insert(Fornecedor fornecedor)
        {
            return this.repository.InsertFornecedor(fornecedor);
        }

        public void Remove(Fornecedor fornecedor)
        {
            this.repository.RemoveFornecedor(fornecedor);
        }

        public IList<Fornecedor> GetAll()
        {
            return this.repository.GetAllFornecedores();
        }

        public Fornecedor Update(Fornecedor fornecedor)
        {
            return this.repository.UpdateFornecedor(fornecedor);
        }
    }
}
```

Observe que no código acima é instanciado um objeto da classe Repository. Segue abaixo o código da classe.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ModelProject;

namespace PersistenceProject
{
    public class Repository
    {
        private IList<Fornecedor> fornecedores = new List<Fornecedor>();

        public Fornecedor InsertFornecedor(Fornecedor fornecedor)
        {
            this.fornecedores.Add(fornecedor);
            return fornecedor;
        }

        public void RemoveFornecedor(Fornecedor fornecedor)
        {
            this.fornecedores.Remove(fornecedor);
        }

        public IList<Fornecedor> GetAllFornecedores()
        {
             return this.fornecedores;
        }

        public Fornecedor UpdateFornecedor(Fornecedor fornecedor)
        {
             this.fornecedores[this.fornecedores.IndexOf(fornecedor)] = fornecedor;
             return fornecedor;
        }
     }
 }
```

Código da Classe NotaEntrada:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ModelProject
{
    public class NotaEntrada
    {
         public Guid Id { get; set; }
         public string Numero { get; set; }
         public Fornecedor FornecedorNota { get; set; }
         public DateTime DataEmissao { get; set; }
         public DateTime DataEntrada { get; set; }
         public IList<ProdutoNotaEntrada> Produtos { get; set; }

         public NotaEntrada()
         {
             this.Produtos = new List<ProdutoNotaEntrada>();
         }

         public void RegistrarProduto(ProdutoNotaEntrada produto)
         {
              if (!this.Produtos.Contains(produto))
                  this.Produtos.Add(produto);
         }

         public void RemoverProduto(ProdutoNotaEntrada produto)
         {
               this.Produtos.Remove(produto);
         }

         public void RemoverTodosProdutos()
         {
              this.Produtos.Clear();
         }
    }
}
```

Por fim, o código que está lançando a exceção:

```
private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var notaEntrada = new NotaEntrada()
    {
        Id = (txtIDNotaEntrada.Text == string.Empty ? Guid.NewGuid() : new Guid(txtIDNotaEntrada.Text)),
        DataEmissao = dtpEmissao.Value,
        DataEntrada = dtpEntrada.Value,
        FornecedorNota = (Fornecedor)cbxFornecedor.SelectedItem, // Acredito que aqui seja a linha do erro, pois quando eu removo essa linha, o código executa normalmente, porém não apresenta o valor do fornecedor escolhido no GRID
        Numero = txtNumero.Text
     };

        notaEntrada = (txtIDNotaEntrada.Text == string.Empty ? this.controller.Insert(notaEntrada) : this.controller.Update(notaEntrada));
        dgvNotasEntrada.DataSource = null;
        dgvNotasEntrada.DataSource = this.controller.GetAllNotaEntrada();
        ClearControlsNota();
 }
```

Código que popula os valores no ComboBox:

```
  private void InicializaComboBoxs()
  {
        cbxFornecedor.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Fornecedor fornecedor in this.fornecedorController.GetAll())
        {
            cbxFornecedor.Items.Add(fornecedor.Nome);
        }
  }
```

Comment: `SelectedItem` é uma string com o que está escrito no combobox no momento... A conversão não faz sentido.

Comment: é porque o propriedade da sua classe é um tipo de outra classe, ou seja, FornecedorNota é do tipo Fornecedor e você está querendo fazer um `cast` do Combox que não é do mesmo tipo.

Comment: Vocês poderia me mostrar um código de exemplo para eu poder comparar o meu erro?

Comment: @DanilloVicttor Não tem o que mostrar, pequeno gafanhoto. Seria bom se você mostrasse o código que usas para preencher o combo, aí podemos tentar te ajudar.

Comment: @DanilloVicttor Coloca na pergunta, filho

Comment: @LINQ coloquei já o código... está na final da pergunta

Comment: agora tem que usar: `cbxFornecedor.DataSource = this.fornecedorController.GetAll(); cbxFornecedor.DisplayMember = "Nome";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está apenas adicionando os nomes dos fornecedores no ComboBox. Não faz sentido querer converter o `SelectedItem` para o tipo `Fornecedor` porque os itens do combo são apenas *strings*.

Tem diversas formas de você fazer o preenchimento do Combo.

Uma forma é definir a propriedade **`DataSource`** (a fonte de dados) como a lista de fornecedores  e definir a propriedade `DisplayName` como a propriedade que você deseja mostrar (o nome, neste caso).

```
cbxFornecedor.DataSource = fornecedorController.GetAll(); 
cbxFornecedor.DisplayName = "Nome";
```

Agora, seu código deve funcionar normalmente porque o **itens** no ComboBox são instâncias de `Fornecedor` e não *strings*.

---

Eu criei um projeto de exemplo. Veja funcionando abaixo.

O código está disponível no [**GitHub**](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/tree/master/CSharp%20WinForms/315799).

[image: Exemplo de execução do código abaixo]

Código do *form*

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cbxFornecedor.DataSource = Fornecedor.GetAll();
    cbxFornecedor.DisplayMember = "Nome";
}

private void btSelecionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fornecedor = (Fornecedor) cbxFornecedor.SelectedItem;
    txtId.Text = fornecedor.Id.ToString();
    txtNome.Text = fornecedor.Nome;
    txtObservacao.Text = fornecedor.Observacao;
}
```

Código da classe `Fornecedor`

```
public class Fornecedor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }

    public static List<Fornecedor> GetAll()
    {
        return new List<Fornecedor>
        {
            new Fornecedor { Id = 1, Nome = "Joaquim Pedro Soares", Observacao = "Início em fevereiro" },
            new Fornecedor { Id = 2, Nome = "Marcos Borba da Silva", Observacao = "Sem descrição" },
            new Fornecedor { Id = 3, Nome = "Martina dos Anjos", Observacao = "Lorem observação" },
            new Fornecedor { Id = 4, Nome = "Mário Roberto do Amaral", Observacao = "Fornecedor de bolachas" },
            new Fornecedor { Id = 5, Nome = "Jonathan da Silva Sauro", Observacao = "Nada a declarar" },
            new Fornecedor { Id = 6, Nome = "Maria Francisca Parker", Observacao = "Pagar adiantado" },
            new Fornecedor { Id = 7, Nome = "Roberta de Leão Moraes", Observacao = "Sem observação" }
        };
    }
}
```